# How to copy data from one sqlite database to another sqlite database in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I Have 2 database which is `PosOrderPayment` and another is `TempPosOrderPayment` both have the same table which `Orders` with the same attributes and columns. the problem is I want to get all data from `TempPosOrderPayment` and save it into `PosOrderPayment`. I want to do the code at the Business Layer(OrderBo). I want to avoid reinserting data that's why I want to retrieve and copy the data and row from other table in other database since this two things will be insert from 2 different application.

Right now I have something look like this

// this in my Payment Application

```
    public void InsertOrder(Order order)
    {
        try
        {               
         using (PosOrderPaymentDBContext db = new PosOrderPaymentDBContext())
            {
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

      }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
            customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

//this is my Cashier application

```
 public void InsertOrder(Order order)
    {
        try
        {        
         using (tempPosOrderPaymentDBContext db = new tempPosOrderPaymentDBContext())
            {
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
 }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
            customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

is there a way ?

the scenario is like 
When user click button `Pay` in cashier application it will save all the data in table `Orders` in `TempPosOrderPayment` database then it will go to Payment application. when user click button `Payment` in payment application it will copy all data in table `Orders` inside `TempPosOrderPayment` and save it into table `Orders` inside `PosOrderPayment` database

after the payment complete the table `Orders` in `TempPosOrderPayment` database will be empty. and this insert-copy-remove will repeat every time user run the application

Comment: @Avinash can you perhaps give an example. sorry I'm new in this :)

Comment: as this is SQLite, maybe you can just copy your db file?

Comment: @vasily.sib Thank you for your opinion. does it using code to copy the db file. if possible I need something that need code because this copy data will be use every time user run the application.

Comment: [File.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you first capture the customer's order in the Cashier application and persist it in a database 1 (`TempPosOrderPayment`), then a payment is confirmed, and you copy this order in the Payment application to another database (`PosOrderPayment`).

Assuming you must be using two separate databases, then the scenario above looks reasonable although prone to errors - what if you forget to delete a record from `TempPosOrderPayment` after copying it over to `PosOrderPayment`?

If you were able to work in one database only, you could use some status field to indicate the business status of the order (Received, Confirmed, Paid...) and also use transactions to ensure your data stays consistent.

Comment: Hi Tomas. yes you understand me correctly. But unfortunately I need to work on 2 database for some reason. But its okay I've found the way I want. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you post the answer here, that will help people like me who are looking for the same .